# Optimize Heroku server code without overheating server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, request

I got a heroku server from which I am sending a lot of requests.

I want to send as many requests as possible in the shortest amount of time.

If I send too many requests at a time, the server will overheat and miss out on some of them. Similarly, if I only send one request at a time, I will find myself spending a lot of precious dyno hours which is not desirable either.

So the question is: 
**How can I send as many requests as possible in the shortest amount of time without overheating the server?**

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean: "overhead" is certainly the wrong word. Do you mean overheat? That would make a bit more sense, but it's not the problem here. If Heroku's dynos stop processing requests it probably isn't due to overheating.

Comment: In any case, you'll probably have to figure this out by trial and error. There's no magic formula.

Comment: @Chris If you try to do too much at once, the server will first slow down to try and cope with it, if it continues and the amount of work just increases the server will eventually shut down. (That's what I was told by the costumer support at Heorku)